# section Header not selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

**In my Last Question extension Now I am able to select rows in a particular section but How section will select using buttons**

```
 - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
Header *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
UILabel *name = (UILabel*) [headerView.contentView viewWithTag:section+2];
UILabel *code = (UILabel*) [headerView.contentView viewWithTag:section+4];
name.text = [_data[section] valueForKey:@"Name"] ;
code.text=[_data[section] valueForKey:@"Code"] ;
imagebutton=(UIButton*)[headerView.contentView viewWithTag:section+3];
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
[imagebutton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[imagebutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    if(headerArray.count>0)
    {
        if([headerArray containsObject:@"0"])
        {
            UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
            [imagebutton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [imagebutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
        else
        {
            UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_floating_done_@1x"];
            [imagebutton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [imagebutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        }
}
UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[headerView.contentView viewWithTag:section+1];
[btn addTarget: self
        action: @selector(buttonClicked:event:)
forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return headerView;
}
```

*This is My header view here I am using button to select section*

```
 (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender event:(id)event
 {
    if(imagebutton.currentImage == [UIImage imageNamed:@""] )
    {
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_floating_done_@1x"];
        [imagebutton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imagebutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        [imagebutton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imagebutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
 }
```

> [TableView CheckMarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948399/tableview-checkmarks)

For details, I am giving my last question link here my data and tableview delegates available

My problem is I am not able to select the first section if I click any row two sections are selected

If particular section row selects that section only select and if section select all rows will select.

Please give a clear example for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect the header UIView to a property in your .h file.